# user_presave and user status

Tags: 7

I have written this hook in my custom module, just to track the status changes of the users.

```
/**
 * Implements @see hook_user_presave
 */
function mycustommodule_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {  
$account_user_id_=$account->uid ;       
 $new_status=  $edit['status'];
 $previous_status= $account->status;
watchdog('attention', 
     'User  %ui changed status to: %newstat, previous status was %previousstat', 
     array('%ui' => $account_user_id_, '%newstat' => $new_status, '%previousstat' => $previous_status, WATCHDOG_NOTICE));
}
```

I noticed for example that when a user activates his newly created account by clicking on the link sent by email, the status moves to 1 which is good .
But I also noticed other message that I couldn't know its cause:

"user 34 changed status to: , previous status was 1" . What makes the status of a user moves from 1 to  null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `NULL` for `$edit['status']` because the status hasn't been changed. The functions that calls [`user_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/7.x), which invokes [`hook_user_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7.x) contain the following code.

```php
// user_profile_form_submit()

$account_unchanged = clone $account;
entity_form_submit_build_entity('user', $account, $form, $form_state);

// Populate $edit with the properties of $account, which have been edited on
// this form by taking over all values, which appear in the form values too.
$edit = array_intersect_key((array) $account, $form_state['values']);
user_save($account_unchanged, $edit, $category);
```

```php
// user_register_submit()

$account = $form['#user'];
entity_form_submit_build_entity('user', $account, $form, $form_state);

// Populate $edit with the properties of $account, which have been edited on
// this form by taking over all values, which appear in the form values too.
$edit = array_intersect_key((array) $account, $form_state['values']);
$account = user_save($account, $edit);
```

As the comment says, `$edit` contains only the account properties that have been changed, not every property. If you want to obtain the status value, you should use the following code.

```php
$new_status = isset($edit['status']) ? $edit['status'] : $account->status;
```

Comment: Perfect answer I want now to tackle the case where the user activates his account by email ..I did the following and it worked  `if ($account->uid  && $account->status === "0" && $edit['status']==1) {echo "hello";} ` .  I want to ask you if my code  "hello" will be executed when I have this case "user 34 changed status to: , previous status was 1" or not ? I can't test it for now but I assume it won't right?  because  `$account->status === "0" ` is not true so we will exit the if condition before reaching the `&& $edit['status']==1` so i won't get an error saying undefined index status right?

Comment: What I care for the most is that I don't want to get this error  undefined index status which I used to get when a user edited his profile and obviously it was caused by his status  that wasn't changed as you have said.

Comment: Just verify the value has been set with `isset($edit['status'])` before accessing it. `$new_status =  $edit['status'];` would cause the *Undefined index* error only when `$edit['status']` doesn't exist, but `$new_status = isset($edit['status']) ? $edit['status'] : $account->status;` won't.

Comment: Thank you !!!!!!